# How to decode shortcodes recursively in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to call shortcodes recursively.
The idea is to use shortcodes within a shortcode, I tried exploding the string tried some other logics but none worked.

Can you please help.

I'll share an example below.

```
add_shortcode( 'first', function ( $attr ) {
    return 'First ' . $attr['key1'] . ' ' . $attr['key2'];
} );
add_shortcode( 'second', function ( $attr ) {
    return 'Second ' . $attr['key1'] . ' ' . $attr['key2'];
} );
add_shortcode( 'third', function ( $attr ) {
    return 'Third ' . $attr['key1'];
} );
```

Now suppose the string is `$string = '[first  key1="[second key1="abcd" key2="shortcode"]" key2="[third key1="shortcode"]"]';`

OR `$string = '[first  key1="[second key1="abcd" key2="[third key1="shortcode"]"]" key2="[third key1="shortcode"]"]';`

Now most probably the output for first string should be something like this: `'First Second abcd shortcode Third shortcode'`

And for the second one should be something like this: `'First Second abcd Third shortcode Third shortcode'`

But I am not getting the result.
Can someone help me to create a function which takes a string and recursively checks for the shortcode and then execute them (do_shortcode).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out on my own how to achieve this.

Took some break and after that the solution just came into my mind.

I am adding the code below for people who might face the same issue in future.

```
    public function maybe_parse_nested_merge_tags( $string ) {
        $position_end = strpos( $string, ']' );
        if ( false === $position_end ) {
            return $string;
        }

        $split          = str_split( $string, $position_end );
        $position_start = strrpos( $split[0], '[', - 1 );

        if ( false === $position_start ) {
            return $string;
        }

        $shortcode_array = explode( '[', $split[0] );
        $shortcode       = end( $shortcode_array );
        $result          = do_shortcode( '[' . $shortcode . ']' );

        $string = str_replace( '[' . $shortcode . ']', $result, $string );

        return $this->maybe_parse_nested_merge_tags( $string );
    }
```